# How to the get the Wordpress Media Search to include tags?

Tags: wordpress

I've added tags to all Media items with this code:

```
function wptp_add_tags_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_tags_to_attachments' );
```

It works great expect one thing. If I search for a media file in the Admin Media Library it does not work with tags.

How can I get the Admin Media Library to include the tags in the search?

Comment: do you mean you need to search media with the tags added to that media. Suppose if test is added to a media, so if you search for test keyword then you should get that media in the results? Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using WordPress action hooks. You need to update the WordPress default search query when searching attachments using hooks **posts_where**, **posts_join** and **posts_groupby**.

Please add below to your themes **functions.php**

```
function custom_attachments_join( $join, $query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    //if we are not on admin or the current search is not on attachment return
    if(!is_admin() || (!isset($query->query['post_type']) || $query->query['post_type'] != 'attachment')) 
        return $join;

    //  if current query is the main query and a search...
    if( is_main_query() && is_search() )
    {
        $join .= "
        LEFT JOIN
        {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
        LEFT JOIN
        {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN
        {$wpdb->terms} ON {$wpdb->terms}.term_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id ";
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'custom_attachments_join', 10, 2 );

function custom_attachments_where( $where, $query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    //if we are not on admin or the current search is not on attachment return
    if(!is_admin() || (!isset($query->query['post_type']) || $query->query['post_type'] != 'attachment'))
        return $where;

    //  if current query is the main query and a search...
    if( is_main_query() && is_search() )
    {
        //  explictly search post_tag taxonomies
        $where .= " OR ( 
                        ( {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy IN('post_tag') AND {$wpdb->terms}.name LIKE '%" . $wpdb->escape( get_query_var('s') ) . "%' )
                       )";

    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_attachments_where', 10, 2 );

function custom_attachments_groupby( $groupby, $query )
{

    global $wpdb;

    //if we are not on admin or the current search is not on attachment return
    if(!is_admin() || (!isset($query->query['post_type']) || $query->query['post_type'] != 'attachment'))
        return $groupby;

    //  if current query is the main query and a search...
    if( is_main_query() && is_search() )
    {
        //  assign the GROUPBY
        $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    }

    return $groupby;

}
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'custom_attachments_groupby', 10, 2 );
```

What these functions does is:

1. `custom_attachments_join` functions joins `term_relationships` and `term_taxonomy` for giving us ability to search for tags
2. `custom_attachments_where` function modifies the WordPress default where condition to include our search terms to search for `taxonomy` or `terms` fields
3. `custom_attachments_groupby` adds group by condition to remove duplicate posts if any.

These functions also check whether we are **searching** for **attachment** and if we are performing the search in the **WordPress** admin area.

Please check with this links for more reference on the hooks I have used.

- [**posts_join**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join)
- **[posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where)**
- **[posts_groupby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_groupby)**

Hope this helps you

Comment: `$wpdb->escape( get_query_var('s')` should be replaced by `$wpdb->_prepare( get_query_var('s')` for `escape` is outdated. I applied the functions to a custom category by replacing `post_tag` by `my-custom-categories` and it works. Thanks for the script.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin's changelog page says that it searches media tags added by its program:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-tags/changelog/

If you're building your own plugin, I recommend grabbing their code and seeing what they're doing. Otherwise, their plugin seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Sabari's solution doesn't work for the search-form in the "Add Media" - section.

I am using the following function in my **functions.php** (code based on the "Media Search Enhanced" plugin by Yoren Chang):

```
function myprefix_posts_clauses( $pieces ) {

  global $wp_query, $wpdb;

  $vars = $wp_query->query_vars;
  if ( empty( $vars ) ) {
    $vars = ( isset( $_REQUEST['query'] ) ) ? $_REQUEST['query'] : array();
  }

  // Rewrite the where clause
  if ( ! empty( $vars['s'] ) && ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'query-attachments' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) || 'attachment' == $vars['post_type'] ) ) {
    $pieces['where'] = " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private')";

    if ( class_exists('WPML_Media') ) {
      global $sitepress;
      //get current language
      $lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();
      $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND wpml_translations.element_type='post_attachment' AND wpml_translations.language_code = %s", $lang );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $vars['post_parent'] ) ) {
      $pieces['where'] .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_parent = " . $vars['post_parent'];
    } elseif ( 0 === $vars['post_parent'] ) {
      // Get unattached attachments
      $pieces['where'] .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_parent = 0";
    }

    if ( ! empty( $vars['post_mime_type'] ) ) {
      // Use esc_like to escape slash
      $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $vars['post_mime_type'] ) . '%';
      $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_mime_type LIKE %s", $like );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $vars['m'] ) ) {
      $year = substr( $vars['m'], 0, 4 );
      $monthnum = substr( $vars['m'], 4 );
      $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND YEAR($wpdb->posts.post_date) = %d AND MONTH($wpdb->posts.post_date) = %d", $year, $monthnum );
    } else {
      if ( ! empty( $vars['year'] ) && 'false' != $vars['year'] ) {
        $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND YEAR($wpdb->posts.post_date) = %d", $vars['year'] );
      }

      if ( ! empty( $vars['monthnum'] ) && 'false' != $vars['monthnum'] ) {
        $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND MONTH($wpdb->posts.post_date) = %d", $vars['monthnum'] );
      }
    }

    // search for keyword "s"
    $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $vars['s'] ) . '%';
    $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND ( ($wpdb->posts.ID LIKE %s) OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s) OR ($wpdb->posts.guid LIKE %s) OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE %s) OR ($wpdb->posts.post_excerpt LIKE %s)", $like, $like, $like, $like, $like );
    $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s)", $like );
    $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s)", $like );

    // Get taxes for attachements
    $taxes = get_object_taxonomies( 'attachment' );
    if ( ! empty( $taxes ) ) {
      $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR (tter.slug LIKE %s) OR (ttax.description LIKE %s) OR (tter.name LIKE %s)", $like, $like, $like );
    }

    $pieces['where'] .= " )";

    $pieces['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id";

    // Get taxes for attachements
    $taxes = get_object_taxonomies( 'attachment' );
    if ( ! empty( $taxes ) ) {
      $on = array();
      foreach ( $taxes as $tax ) {
        $on[] = "ttax.taxonomy = '$tax'";
      }
      $on = '( ' . implode( ' OR ', $on ) . ' )';

      $pieces['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS trel ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = trel.object_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS ttax ON (" . $on . " AND trel.term_taxonomy_id = ttax.term_taxonomy_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms AS tter ON (ttax.term_id = tter.term_id) ";
    }

    $pieces['distinct'] = 'DISTINCT';

    $pieces['orderby'] = "$wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
  }

  return $pieces;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'myprefix_posts_clauses', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution benedikt works fine, but the language filter is with the wpml plugin.
I use Polylang and looking for the right way to do the same filter, I can not find a solution even with the Polylang documentation...

There is just this part to change :

```
    if ( class_exists('WPML_Media') ) {
      global $sitepress;
      //get current language
      $lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();
      $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND wpml_translations.element_type='post_attachment' AND wpml_translations.language_code = %s", $lang );
    }
```

by something like that :

```
    if ( function_exists( 'pll_current_language' ) ) {
      //get current language
      $lang = pll_current_language();
      $pieces['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( here I don't know how to write it... );
    }
```

If someone can help ?